# Integrating Tomcat7 and Eclipse Helios on Snow Leopard

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to write a "Hello World" web application using Tomcat and Eclipse, in order to familiarize myself with building Tomcat projects.

So far I've gleaned from Google searches that I need to install Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) to go ahead with it. But when I go to Help->Install New Software I can't find any software update site that is hosting WTP.

My default "Available Software Sites" are Helios, Mylyn for Eclipse Helios, and the Eclipse Project Updates. Do I need to add a new software update site to install WTP? If so, what is the URL? If not, where can I find WTP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates

Also it comes preinstalled if you use 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers' -> http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliossr1

Answer (score 2):

Get the Java EE version of Eclipse.  It has all the needed Eclipse components installed, and you just need to create a server adapter for Tomcat and point it to the unzipped distribution.

I do not know if Tomcat 7 is supported yet.  You may want to use an older, supported version like 6 or 5.5 to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! I suspected that I may have needed EE.

Comment: You don't _need_ the EE version as you can just install the necessary plugins and get the same.  I just happen to like the prepackaged model.